# Controlling the output messages of MCMC function in the adaptMCMC package

Tags: r, mcmc

Curious to know if there's any way to disable the output messages that are printed during a run of the `MCMC()` function in the `adaptMCMC` package. I'm running this function many times and these print statements are filling up my disk.

Here's how it looks (straight from the [manual](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/adaptMCMC/adaptMCMC.pdf)):

```
library(adaptMCMC)
#log-pdf to sample from
p.log <- function(x) {
B <- 0.03 # controls 'bananacity'
-x[1]^2/200 - 1/2*(x[2]+B*x[1]^2-100*B)^2
}

samp <- MCMC(p.log, n=200, init=c(0, 1), scale=c(1, 0.1),
adapt=TRUE, acc.rate=0.234)

  generate 200 samples
```

And the output message is:

```
  |========================================================================================================================================================| 100%
```

My gibbs sampler is much more elaborate than that which results in heavy standard output.

Comment: So somehow the progress bar is being written to disc? I'm not sure how you're capturing the results. Can you just capture and ignore the output from the function, ie `ignore<-capture.output(samp <- MCMC(p.log, n=200, init=c(0, 1), scale=c(1, 0.1),
adapt=TRUE, acc.rate=0.234))` ?

Comment: Yeah that'll work. Thanks!